# How to get all contracts from an Etherscan address?

Tags: blockchain, solidity, truffle, etherscan

Is there a way, like `git clone` in git, to get all the contracts, in the same file structure that was implemented in the project from an Etherscan address?

I mean, the only way is copying each contract individually?

For example, this address:

https://etherscan.io/address/0x1703f8111B0E7A10e1d14f9073F53680d64277A3?utm_source=immunefi#code

There are 35 contracts, if i want to implement locally i have to have all the contracts in the same file structure, how can i do this without having to copy each contract individually?